# Wrong tag created

Tags: support, tags

I have created the tag [*fluen*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluen), but I did not want to.

This is just to alert somebody to delete it as it is unuseful and without any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have accidentally created a tag, simply remove the tag from the question you created it on (this appears to already have been done).

Provided no one else decides to use it, the tag will be automatically cleaned away by the system at the end of the day.

Comment: ok. I have already removed from the question. Thanks for helping

Comment: Really? Is that for any tag with no questions, or just tags created the same day?

Comment: @Michael Former. System automatically cleans away empty tags at the end of the day. I lost a good wiki thanks to it, once. Tags with a single instance are cleaned away after 6 months (adding [untagged] if it was the question's sole tag).

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new about the engine. Is there documentation of this?

Comment: @Pop: Some of the background is in [Jeff's answer to "Should We Zap The Low-Occurrence Tags?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418).  That's where the 6-month rule came from; I'm not sure about the end-of-day rule.

Comment: @Pop Well, there's some writing on the subject [over here in an answer and its comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69916/wait-a-second/69917#69917). While I did know of the end-of-day from experience and word-of-chat, I'm pretty sure I learned it before then in reading some post on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Grace, that link points back at this question.

Comment: @Popular That's intentional. ♪