# Created a tag by mistake

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I accidentally created a tag. How do I delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it)

I retagged a question and accidentally created the [d](/questions/tagged/d) tag. How do I delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the tag. Orphaned tags are automatically deleted daily

Comment: I made the tag on meta.so