# Delete tag [tag:winfroms] as it is a typo

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

[winfroms](/questions/tagged/winfroms) is a typo of [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms).

I would suggest deleting rather than merging as there was only 1 question with it and I have re-tagged it.

Comment: No need to delete anything. The tag will vanish all by itself soon unless new questions will use it. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it?rq=1) as well.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - ah, is that like an auto-clean-up feature! didn't know that. thanks.

Comment: Yes indeed, auto cleanup is proper term. :-)