# Delete the riddle tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Earlier I saw a question which was tagged [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle). This tag seemed completely inactive, it had only 11 questions *most likely each of which ought to be closed (looking through them).*

I decided to go through and remove this tag from each of these questions, as [this question suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it), and voted to close where appropriate.

Was this the correct thing to do? Should I have made a retag request to puzzle?

.

The (similar) [puzzle](/questions/tagged/puzzle) tag has nearly 500 questions and states:

> DO NOT USE - prefer constructive questions, or use tags that describe your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I decided to go through and remove this tag from each of these questions... and voted to close where appropriate.

That sounds perfect to me.  The only reservation I have about *completely* removing a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) is that someone needs to look at each question and decide if they need to be closed or just retagged.  Since you already voted to close where appropriate, those questions are now in a review queue where they'll be closed eventually (that queue is backlogged).