# Can one flag a tag?

Tags: support, tags

I [found a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14096429/1275871) that was tagged by a user with `mysq` when `mysql` was intended.  Should I report this as an error somehow or is `mysq` legitimate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I accidentally created a tag. How do I delete it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're certain it was someone's typo, just remove it from the post, or suggest an edit to do so if you don't have editing privileges, and the tag will be automatically deleted after a set time (midnight UTC).

No flagging is necessary.  If you have proposed an edit rather than editing directly, you *could* leave a brief comment to alert the OP to accept your edit, but that's also not really necessary as he/she will receive a notification that you've suggested an edit.

Comment: Oh, I see know.  I didn't realize one could just type anything as a "tag".  I thought they were "pre-approved".  I did edit and re-tag the question, so I guess it will disappear on its own.

Comment: @BobDuell Anyone over 1500 rep on Stack Overflow (and progressively less on other graduated sites and beta sites) can create tags, so sometimes someone slips when the suggestions start popping up as you type.

Comment: Or sometimes people are lazy and just hit space (instead of clicking on the tag picker) and don't realize that their typo created a new tag.

Comment: @Charles At that point, somewhere, a bat signal goes off and the Tag Posse is summoned... ;)

Comment: @jonsca, it's the tag *Cabal*, thank you very much.