# Questions about to become untagged

Tags: feature-request, tags, 10k-tools, tag-pruning

As far as I know, any tag that is only used once every 6 months is pruned automatically. If that tag was the only one left on a question, the question becomes [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) and history of the previous tag, for good or evil, is lost.

Can we get a list of questions *about* to be orphaned, so that we can retag the question before it is too late?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418

Comment: Related feature request: [Please allow low-occurence tags to be declared persistent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79733). In fact, I'm more worried about questions that have remaining tags, because they'll become harder to find with no warning.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1450571/roomba-period-for-single-use-tags) to determine which single-use tags will be deleted and when, and it also shows the only question using it and which tags it has. You could check this list once in a while and retag when necessary.

[image]

(You originally requested this for Arqade, and tag pruning [has been switched off there already](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5510/168837) but it could still be useful for other communities.)

Answer (score 2):

Can't we just let the community decide on retagging (appropriately, let's hope) [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) questions based on context? They opened up the model nicely to allow anyone to edit anything, surely that can be of use.

Comment: @MPelletier Obviously everyone can now edit; I just thought this would make for an okay 10k tool.

Comment: @badp: And give all the OCD goods to 10Kers only? No, sir, I don't think so.

Comment: That being said, it's high time I join this club. I need to step up my answering, and let retagging go. If there was rep for retagging, I'd be up there with Jon Skeet.

Comment: @MPelletier Remember you can get +2 rep per approved suggested edit. PS: all the OCD goods are _already_ 10kers only. That's the whole point of the 10k tools. :P

Comment: @badp: But that doesn't cover tags, and after 2k, it's pointless since users have full editing privileges. Unless I'm gettint it wrong. That incentive will just make a whole lot of people bubble up to 2K and stall, IMO.

Comment: @MPellitier It covers tags up to the point where you can retag on your own. It covers posts up to the point where you can edit on your own. It covers tag wikis up to the point where you can edit those on your own. However, you need _500 edits_ to get 1k, after which suggested edits stop generating rep completely... I don't see anybody getting "rich" with suggested edits.

Comment: @badp: I'm not suggesting they'd get "rich", as you say, just that I realize that the road from 0 to 2k is now a bit shorter, that's all.