# Please allow low-occurrence tags to be declared persistent

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-pruning

[Single-use tags are pruned after six months.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) Sometimes, this removes spurious tags. Sometimes, this removes legitimate tags.

After a quick look on [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags?page=9&tab=popular), I see plenty of legitimate tags that are at risk. I would like a way to declare that some tags are legitimate and should never be pruned. This could be a 10k tool, for instance.

I realize this might not scale on Stack Overflow, but it would work for smaller sites (I'm using Unix as an example because it's the one I know best). A [warning when tags are about to expire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79609/questions-about-to-become-untagged) would be a helpful complement.

Comment: I think this is a great idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Tags that have a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki) [no longer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/127700/5) expire even if they are only applied to one question. Therefore, you can vet a tag by writing a tag wiki for it.

Comment: Do we have a reference besides the 'status-completed' tag on that question?  It's not listed in the [Recent Features](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Comment: @LanceRoberts I never got any official reply. I went to search and found [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/141565) and [that](http://askubuntu.com/q/197578) question which have a single-use tag with a tag wiki and hasn't been edited in almost a year. I can't be sure that there hasn't been another question with these tag until recently though. The recent features list is maintained by the community, I'm not surprised that a discrete edit to make one question [meta-tag:status-completed] went unnoticed.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to delete a low occurence tag, say, two times.  If the tag reappears after that it's permanent.

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough knowledge about the tag to know that it should stay, it's not hard to come up with a suitable question that uses it.

Post such a question, use the tag, and the problem goes away - the tag stays.

Comment: I agree, this is the only sane solution -- if it's such a valid tag, then it should be used at least once in six months by *someone* else.