# Misspelled 'guassian' tag

Tags: discussion, tags

While performing a review task I came across the [guassian](/questions/tagged/guassian) tag.

The suggested edit was actually a comment, stating

> I think this is a misspelling for gaussian. It probably should be deleted.

I rejected the edit, since it's not a valid edit to the tag, but I think the commenter may be right: looks like a misspelling and I agree that it should be deleted.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there are no questions tagged with it, it'll be automatically culled within 24 hours.

Good catch.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: There was one question, but I just retagged it, since it became obvious after reading its content. I wasn't aware of the automatic deletion, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: It will be delete even if there _is_ a tag wiki?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Unless something's changed re: [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki).  No, tag wikis can't save orphaned tags.