# Tags page and number of questions

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I was thinking of doing some tag cleanup and/or wiki creation so I looked at the tags page by popular and look at the least popular (say on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags?page=33&tab=popular)). I was expecting that these would be tags with zero or low numbers but I found many with no numbers. These are mainly synonyms (currently the last one is macintosh which is merged with the 9th most common tag) and they do have wiki entries.

Is there a way to filter out the synonyms? or to get a display of just the uncommon tags

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to filter out the synonyms? or to get a display of just the uncommon tags

You could use [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) to find tags which haven't got many question. It seems that the Tags table contains also some tag synonyms, but you can filter those out:

- List of tags which are synonymized: [Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1420250/list-of-tags-which-are-synonymized), [Ask Different](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/1420250/list-of-tags-which-are-synonymized), [Mathematics](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1420250/list-of-tags-which-are-synonymized)
- List of tags which are not synonymized: [Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1420249/list-of-tags-which-are-not-synonymized), [Ask Different](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/1420249/list-of-tags-which-are-not-synonymized), [Mathematics](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1420249/list-of-tags-which-are-not-synonymized)
- The smallest tags which are not synonymized: [Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1420417/the-smallest-tags-which-are-not-synonymized), [Ask Different](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/1420417/the-smallest-tags-which-are-not-synonymized), [Mathematics](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1420417/the-smallest-tags-which-are-not-synonymized)

You should keep in mind that the data in SEDE are updated only once a week.

---

As mentioned in other answers, the tags which have no questions are [removed daily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info). The tags which have only one question are removed after six months [unless they have tag-wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki).

Answer (score 1):

I believe (in SO's case), you get to tumbleweed territory around [page 925](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=924&tab=popular) of the tags page, sorted by popularity.

For AskDifferent, with only 30-something pages of tags (after your cleaning, I presume), I think it can still be done manually. The [Tag Synonyms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) page reduces pagination to just 3 pages on AD, so that's quite easy to work with, IMO.

While I think some better filtering would be beneficial for the larger sites, they also have a larger contingency of people hunting for tag wikis to improve, somewhat reducing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since tags without posts will be automatically deleted as part of the nightly cleanup script, if you see a tag without any questions, it is either a synonym or will be deleted that night.

Scanning backwards when sorted by popularity seems to be the best way (which is obviously faster on smaller sites).  If you are intent on cleaning up tags, you should just search back until you find the tags that have x1 or more.

For Ask Different, it looks like they start on [page 26](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags?page=26&tab=popular)