# Do you clean up MSO tags? What criteria determines burnination for MSO and SO?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the criteria for determining if an MSO tag should be removed, and is this the same as determining when SO tags should be removed? I never really understand the reasons for most SO tag burninate proposals.

MSO - For example, the following tags on MSO have only 1 question and so seem pretty pointless to me, but would they be zapped?

[annotations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/annotations) 1 question
[websense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websense) 1 question
[automatic-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automatic-votes) 1 question

There are plenty more like that.

Are tags which are not causing any issues ignored and left alone?
Is the same principle applied to SO tags?

Comment: [meta-so] allows for burning of meta tags?

Comment: Funny story. The automatic-votes tag was actually created shortly before they got rid of automatic downvotes for closed questions. So it *used to be* a valid topic that just never had a tag. I suppose you could still use it for the automatic downvote from spam/offensive flags though...

Comment: @animuson even more so.. I've just noticed the only question using the *automatic-votes* tag was to request automatic votes for closed questions be removed... Do you bother cleaning tags of this scenario up, or as it's not a nuisance in any way, just ignore them?

Comment: @hjpotter92 No. We use meta.meta.so for that.

Comment: @James Well, it *is* a valid topic and there are questions out there that would fall under it. It's just not really worth anyone's time to go retag relevant questions with it. I keep a very close eye on new tags here on Meta and tend to kill them off as they're created if they're not any good (usually because they're duplicates). But a tag only having one question is not necessarily an indicator of a bad tag.

Comment: Fair enough. I imagine there aren't too many new ones on MSO for you to sort. thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags older than 6 months [without a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki) and used on only one question are automatically removed by the system. If you happen to be editing a question with a seemingly-useless tag anyway, go ahead and remove it - otherwise, don't worry about it.