# Hovering over synonym tags, but no favorite dialog is displayed

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

When I was going through the tags to check what I've been missing and adding the ones I find interesting to me, I realized that hovering over synonym tags like [wp7](/questions/tagged/wp7), displays a blank dialogue like this one:

> [image: WP7 blank dialogue]

I know I can't follow or favorite the tag synonym itself, because it's not actually a real tag. But I'm expecting them to act the same as a "regular" tag, and allow me to favorite the "real" tag (for eg [windows-phone-7](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7) in case of [wp7](/questions/tagged/wp7)).

Comment: That's a super-emphasizing underline.

Comment: ROFL!! I'm just asking for further "emphasizing" with adding the favorite/followers star on it :D

Comment: Please *don't* change it to match the synonymous tag—the blank popup is currently the only way to know if the tag is a synonym without clicking through.

Comment: @Dori: I'm not sure why would you like to differentiate between them. But don't you think that making them "usable"  and being more explicit about synonym-tags (add text saying so, on the dialog or a symbol may be) is much better for all users? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup dialog now deals with synonyms:
[image: tag synonyms]