# Delete (merge?) javascrip tag

Tags: support, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I accidentally created a tag. How do I delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it)
>   [Shouldn't SO unused tags be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92056/shouldnt-so-unused-tags-be-deleted)

I found a tag on SO named [javascrip](/questions/tagged/javascrip) which is clearly a typo of [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). I thought that I would be able to remove it myself, but it appears that the correct course of action is to post on meta to have it merged (though it has no questions).

Do I have to do anything further or is simply posting a question the appropriate action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's only a couple instances you can just remove them from the posts yourself. If there are *no* instances like here, the tag will get deleted automatically around midnight, so you don't actually need to do anything

Comment: Is that midnight UTC?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes; pretty much everything is UTC on SO

Answer (score 2):

Having that as a synonym is pretty useless, and merging won't do anything, since, as you noted, it doesn't have any questions tagged with it.

Because of this, you don't have to worry about it as it'll disappear on its own after a while.