# Restrict the use of [untagged] for tagging questions

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do not allow users to tag questions with “untagged”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122841/do-not-allow-users-to-tag-questions-with-untagged)

[untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) is abused to post questions without tags. Could this be restricted?

Comment: Well, it's used by the system; do you just mean stop users from posting questions with only that tag? That part makes sense

Comment: Go easy on the downvotes! He simply didn't know..

Comment: Haven't we established by now that downvotes are not a punishment?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122841/do-not-allow-users-to-tag-questions-with-untagged

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) is used by the system when it runs its automatic routine to [delete single-use tags that are over six months old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418), and questions are left without other tags.  Maybe it could be implemented as a moderator-only tag, like the red ones on Meta (in fact make it red), but I don't think 'delete' as your title states is the appropriate way to deal with this.

**EDIT:** Note that I just realized this might not be practical, since editors have to be able to remove the tag when they add correct ones in.  The Team will need to chime in on this.

Comment: `[untagged]` is also automatically applied when a question only has one tag and that tag gets manually burninated by a mod.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I don't see much of an abuse of this tag. The tag is on my [observation list](https://stackexchange.com/filters/19305/small-tags-sites?sort=active), and in the two weeks I've observed it, only migrated questions appeared new with this tag (or someone else was faster with retagging them).

(I suppose the ones which get it through deletion of single-use tags don't appear in the activity list.)

It is actually a good indication of questions who need some love (edits).