# Is there a way to report a typo in a tag to moderators?

Tags: support, tags

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uplaod

Is an obvious typo, it there a way to merge it with [upload](/questions/tagged/upload) or eliminate it?
Or should I flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: Someone just edited this and fixed the issue...

Comment: good point (15 chars)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That misspelled tag was only used once, in such cases it is far easier to just change it by hand. The misspelled tag will be removed [automatically after some time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) (~24 hours), if no question is using it anymore.

I did that for the one question where it was used just now.

If a tag that is used by a significant number of question (>10-20) is misspelled or needs to be renamed, you should post it on meta like you did now. Moderators can rename tags or merge misspelled tags into other tags. But for a hardly-used tag it's not worth it to use these moderator abilities, they are pretty dangerous and not easily undone.

Comment: oic, no wonder I can't find that question

Comment: @ajreal Yep, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new)- you'll find a lot of tags that are newly created but now unused. [uplaod] is in there.

Comment: Even more: if a tag is used by only one question, it [will be removed after 6 months too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418): *[...] a routine that removes tags created more than 6 months ago which have been used only a single time. It will run monthly.*

Answer (score 1):

Commenting and notifying the OP is the easiest option if you don't have edit/retag privileges,

**Edit:** As I see, you have edit privileges. Just edit the tag on the question. Not used tags will cease existence anyway.

Comment: Yup, I can't find any question tag to this typo tag name. Wondering where it come from...