# Rename tag "xhtmlconformance" to "valid-xhtml"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

On Stack Overflow, [xhtmlconformance](/questions/tagged/xhtmlconformance) only has three questions tagged. [valid-xhtml](/questions/tagged/valid-xhtml) has 63 questions. As both tags refer to the same thing, please replace [xhtmlconformance](/questions/tagged/xhtmlconformance) with [valid-xhtml](/questions/tagged/valid-xhtml).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only 3 questions are tagged [xhtmlconformance](/questions/tagged/xhtmlconformance). 2 of them were asked in 2010. The last one was asked this month, but was also tagged [valid-xhtml](/questions/tagged/valid-xhtml).

I have edited these questions, and replaced the tags. This tag will disappear [after 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418). Since the tag was so rarely used, a synonym would not be needed.

Comment: @mc10 You can also do it yourself, because you've got the rights to edit tags. If a tag is clearly a duplicate, and rarely used, don't fear editing.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. I thought you needed tag synonym rights to do that.

Comment: [This privillege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions) allows you to edit tags. Since you have 2k+ rep, you can not only edit tags, but also someone else’s posts.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant actually messing with the tag itself, not editing the posts. I didn't know tags went poof when they were unused.

Comment: +1 Went [poof](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418), haha :D