# Has the criteria for automated tag deletion changed?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems [ruby-2.0](/questions/tagged/ruby-2.0) was automatically deleted because of the [tag-killing process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags). But I thought it was used with more than one question.

Have the criteria changed? I can't see any changes in [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I thought it was used with more than one question

Based on some comparisons between the September and December data dumps, it looks like was actually used on two questions, but [you edited it out](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5702368/revisions) of the second one.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506498/what-will-the-major-minor-differences-be-between-ruby-1-9-2-and-ruby-2-0) is the only other one that I can see that ever had [ruby-2.0](/questions/tagged/ruby-2.0) on it, and although I can't guarantee that there wasn't another question posted with that tag between the two data dumps, I'm fairly certain that the system was behaving as expected in this case.