# What are all the reasons a tag can be eliminated automatically?

Tags: support, tags

I know that if there's only one question with a tag, it gets deleted and the question becomes `untagged`.

What if the tag has a wiki? Does it get deleted too?

What are all the ways this can happen (a tag being deleted automatically that is)?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Tags that are used a single time and are at least six months old are removed monthly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/98786). (This leaves the question "untagged".)

Tags that have **no** questions are removed daily.

Wikis are not removed with their tags (which is why we have a tool for "orphan" tag wikis).

Note also that when a question is migrated, if the receiving site doesn't have any of the tags on the question it will also arrive there "untagged".

Of course, the Stack Exchange developers can step in and remove a tag, but that's a manual process.

Comment: Yes, there is a routine that removes tags created more than 6 months ago which have been used only a single time -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/98786

Comment: Thanks @Robert. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: I think migration can lose tags too.

Comment: @Code: Ugh, you're right. I had that in my original answer, too. Fixing...