# Please delete the "apach2" tag

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the reasons a tag can be eliminated automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121191/what-are-all-the-reasons-a-tag-can-be-eliminated-automatically)

Someone seems to have created an [apach2](/questions/tagged/apach2) tag by accident. No questions are currently tagged with it, so I assume they've been retagged as [apache2](/questions/tagged/apache2) or something.

(This was pointed out by Ben P, who [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/197830), "This must be a typo - apache2 tag exists.")

Comment: No need, it will be auto-dropped within the day. It's all good.