# What happens to those questions whose only tag gets removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

According to the explanation of "**create tags**" privilege:

> new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if
>   they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.

My question is, what happens if the only tag of a question is a newly created tag, and it gets removed automatically after 6 months because it has never been used in any other question. Is it possible for a question in SE sites to be tag-less?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121191/21960

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They get assigned the tag [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged).

These questions should be checked on a regular basis and one of the following actions performed:

1. Retagged with something more useful.
2. Generally edited to improve their quality (including retagging).
3. Closed.
4. Deleted.

Option 2. is by far the best option, but if the question is unsavlageable then options 3 or 4 should be considered.