# Can I or others destroy my own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I created a tag that may be required for my question? But my question is edited and the tag is not required. Can I or others destroy my own tag that has other usages?

Comment: It will age out after a week I think.

Comment: Related: [What are all the reasons a tag can be eliminated automatically?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121191/what-are-all-the-reasons-a-tag-can-be-eliminated-automatically)

Comment: @animuson no it is not my answer, i mean tag that created by myself but used me and other people.

Comment: Only moderators can flat-out destroy a tag. All a user can do is untag all the questions under it and let the system automatically destroy it. I'm not exactly sure what you're asking about, though. Do you have a specific tag you're wondering about?

Comment: he might mean [tag:web-console] as this is from his last question and got vanished while editing question. And has now no other question tagged.

Comment: @animuson No, we can't (unfortunately), only SE employees can. Merging is the only thing we can do with tags that regular users can't.