# Someone create a objective-c-modules tag for me?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I'm a little rep shy of creating objective-c-modules tag for this question: [Obj-C Modules don't work in workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406251/obj-c-modules-dont-work-in-workspace)

Comment: Could you explain why you think it is needed and not covered by objective-c tag?

Comment: I know you're aware of the rep requirement, but have a related link anyways: [Can we please have the [foo\] tag on SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-so)

Comment: @nijansen I figured if perl has a module tag why not for obj-c now that it has them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added to that to that question - I agree with the idea, and I'm slightly surprised it wasn't there before.

**But**, it won't necessarily stay there: (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121191/what-are-all-the-reasons-a-tag-can-be-eliminated-automatically))

- Tags that are **used a single time** and are **at least six months old** are removed monthly.
- Tags that have no questions are removed daily.

So, if another community member with edit privs disagrees with me and removes the tag, it will be removed from the system within 24 hours. Also, if it isn't used again within six months, it will be removed from both the system and your question.