# Delete the 'vsdbcmd' tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

While asking a question about VS2010 database projects I saw there is a [vsdbcmd](/questions/tagged/vsdbcmd) tag, but it only has one question tagged. The question is also tagged as [database-project](/questions/tagged/database-project), which I think is more appropriate. *vsdbcmd.exe* is just the tool that VS2010 uses to deploy database projects; any question about it will have to involve database projects.

I think this tag can be removed from that one question, and deleted. (It also has no tag wiki or any other description.)

EDIT:

OK, so there are more questions that I thought, because I'm apparently blind. (I kept seeing at the "faq" tab on the tag page, which had only 1 question.)

I still think the tag is still redundant. Part of the reason I came here to ask about deleting it was because I couldn't decide if I should tag my own question above VSDBCMD with one or both of the appropriate tags. But, with that many uses, is it still worth checking those questions to see if there's any use for `vsdbcmd` tag by itself (which I'm willing to do)?

Comment: And: tags that are only used once are removed too, but [that takes 6 months](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) and in the meantime someone might select it from the auto-suggest.

Comment: One question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsdbcmd

Comment: Perhaps it should be made a synonym? If they're really that closely related but yet that far apart spelling-wise, it would be helpful to show the single tag no matter what way the user starts typing it.

Comment: Actually, I was going to suggest database-project as a synonym, but now I'm wondering of that's not specific *enough*; its really a "visual-studio-database-project"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be bold and remove the tag yourself. Orphaned tags are automatically deleted in a day or so, so you don't have to worry about that.

Tags are mainly for filtering purposes. This one is too localized (a search works just as well).

Any tag (not recently created) with only a few questions is usually a candidate for burnination.

Edit: [Wait... One question? I see 30.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsdbcmd)

---

In the case of lots of tagged questions, come to meta and ask (check). Get community approval (sort of check). Either retag manually for relatively less questions (20 questions-- so it's fine here), or hope for the devs to do it. You can also request a blacklist.

Comment: neat, I did not know that. Question has been edited!

Comment: when i click that link, i get no results; did I do something?

Comment: Er, I see 20 :-)

Comment: Er, @Michael, need glasses? ;-) *You are on the FAQ tab.
There are no frequently asked questions at the moment.
Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?*

Comment: @Michael you are probably filtering by featured or something. Check the tabs.

Comment: @Arjan Me=lazy. I see two pages, 15 per page. No need to verify if page 2 is full ;-)

Comment: Ah, but there's quite a huge number in the top right corner. No need to count anything at all ;-)

Comment: @Arjan on desktop, that is.. Even more effort to switch. :p

Comment: @Arjan, yes, once the 1 FAQ was gone and I actually read the page I realized I was just being dumb :\