# What is the purpose of the [blank-page] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is the [blank-page](/questions/tagged/blank-page) tag necessary? I realise that there are cases where code could result in a blank page, but since a) the tag doesn't have a tag wiki and I don't think there is a way to describe the tag in a way that isn't overly general (or useless), and b) the tags that it's associated with seem like they're somewhat [all over the place](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77294/what-other-tags-are-used-on-questions-with-a-given-tag?TagName=blank-page) (I hope my query is correct).

Should it just be left as is or removed? Do superfluous tags like this cause any harm by being left around? It isn't as low-usage as the tags the [algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/187647) takes care of, but I'm still not convinced it has a benefit.

Comment: The `blank-page` tag wiki is intentionally left blank.

Comment: [Maybe I'll just make a little mark here and there...](http://xkcd.com/608/)

Comment: @BilltheLizard The question still remains, though. Does the tag serve a purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that tag serves a useful purpose.  Nobody follows it, it doesn't have a tag wiki to describe what it's used for, and I can't imagine it being used as a search term or a tag filter.  As you pointed out, it's used in conjunction with a wide variety of other tags, so it doesn't look like `blank-page` is a thing in some specific programming language.  It looks like people are just using it to describe a symptom.

It doesn't really do any harm to leave the tag, but removing it would free up a spot on those edited posts for one more meaningful tag.  If you edit these tags out, please take a moment to try and think of a meaningful tag to replace it with on each question.  (As always, look for other meaningful edits to make.)