# Review task for untagged questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, review, untagged-questions

In certain cases, questions will arrive with [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged), such as via migration and no destination tag, or the only tag being removed. This leaves questions in the untagged state, which desires a fix. Often, these tags take while to remove due to the lack of attention to them. It would help to have them enter a separate review task so they can be quickly and easily tagged by human attention.

Comment: This would be useful to have.

Comment: agree, untagged questions are unlikely to receive any care from the community (new answers, edit fix, voting, etc), but they keep appearing in google search results disappointing visitors because of the low quality.

Comment: Furthermore, older questions that have been newly tagged don't appear near the top of a date sorted `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/<tag>` page.

Comment: A *separate* review task seems like overkill for this. Especially since it's almost always 0 for sites other than Stack Overflow. Maybe it could be rolled up into a more general "needs editing" task?

Comment: [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) for the review task.  You're welcome.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you very much. It's just that nobody seems to look since they're not in review-beta.

Comment: I'd go further and say, make a queue for all questions with less than three (or two?) tags that have not yet received a tag edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to point out what I feel is an issue with the currently accepted answer (no offense intended, please see my quote only as an opinion).

Let me quote:

> There are currently 167 untagged questions, well 164. The vast majority (all, bar maybe this one but I have no idea what's going on in it) are Off-Topic or Not Constructive.

This indeed indicates that about 150 questions are deletable/closeable. But also seems to forget the situation on *other sites*. If you go outside the main site, untagged questions are for the most migrated questions - for example on SharePoint overflow as now we have 39 untagged questions that no one retagged. I know, 39 is a small number, but consider that compared to stackoverflow all SharePoint overflow is made of small numbers. Problem is: those questions were migrated because on the migrated site they are reasonable and shouldn't be closed/deleted - the whole idea behind migration is to **salvage** a question that may otherwise die.

I personally see an incentive to retag untagged questions as useful. It doesn't need to be a whole new review task (for example I have the untagged task as a favorite, so a simple search is enough), but a badge could give people the needed incentive to perform some cleanup.

Somebody suggested that question cannot be migrated if no tag exist on the migration site, and thus cannot end up as untagged because of migration. I would disagree. Don't have the rep to check, but I assume that at last diamond-puyonbearded-unicorned-mega-admins can. This was migrated, and ended up untagged on SharePoint.

[image: migrated untagged question]

The [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049086/how-to-find-the-last-visited-user-and-file-downloaded-user-in-sharepoint?noredirect=1) had a SharePoint tag, that doesn't exist on the other side.

Comment: You can't migrate a question if none of the tags are on the destination site. It gets rejected. In principle I agree though a review task is probably over the top. The problem is that these get forgotten.

Comment: are you sure? Not that I don't want to belive you, but I have the felling you may be wrong. See the edit to the post.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards That question has no edit history(before me tagging it). And, it had `sharepoint` before migration, and Sharepoint.SE does not have that tag(since it is useless in categorizing).

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ - just my point there. The question ended up as untagged because of the migration, and it was migrated because we wanted to save it/avoid deletion. In that direction, any incentive for people to review and tag it on the new site would be good. PS: Thanks for the retag, ObsessiveSSOℲ.

Comment: Questions can't be migrated (by anyone except I guess devs) if none of their tags exist on the target side — *unless* one or more of the tags on the source side match a particular blacklist on the destination of "top-level tags that every question has implicitly by definition and should never be added". [sharepoint] on SharePoint is one such; [english] on EL&U is another.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently [167 untagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged), well 164. The vast majority (all, bar maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003719/hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classnotreg) but I have no idea what's going on in it) are Off-Topic or Not Constructive.

I think it would probably be better if all [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) questions were automatically closed and therefore appeared in the delete / re-open queues.

At least then there's no work needed to create a new queue and if most of them deserve deletion they're in the right place.

---

ObsessiveFOSS has suggested, in the comments, a single automatic close-vote rather than a blunderbuss full. This works slightly better as you then have to have a number of people decide to close in keeping with the community closing ethos. They then appear auto-magically in a review queue.

Comment: What should the close reason be?  Do we need a new one just for this?

Comment: I think off-topic is best. If there's no valid tags for a question then it's not really _on_ topic...

Comment: @Ben: They only have no tags because when they're migrated, they can't ensure the same tags exist, so they just remove them altogether.

Comment: A migration get's rejected if not one of the tags exists on the target site, though I can't find the reference. These are more likely to be [Jeff's fault](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) most definitely don't look like they were migrated to SO.

Comment: Maybe them getting an automatic closevote is the best way to go, instead of closing immediately? They'll just land in the closevote queue.

Comment: That works too... it's probably better in fact!

Comment: Should I start an answer with that alternative, or do you want to edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Is this really necessary when, in the past, there hasn't been a review system for these posts, and their count is only at 164?

I simply question whether it would be a rapidly growing list, like suggested edits. A few people could spend a day or two going through the tag page and doing this themselves, and even earn a badge for it.

I just don't see the significance of this if the list isn't growing quickly anyways, and migrations aren't happening all too often.

Comment: But, they all need closing... and probably deleting as well if you look at them. That requires a lot of people to look at them and deal with it.