# Untagged question cleanup posse, Aug 2012 iteration

Tags: discussion, clean-up

[untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) is back, <del>and nearly 170 137 122 questions strong</del> **but we've whittled it down to a handful of questions** from nearly 170, and four of those are already closed. On the surface, it looks like someone burninated [interview-questions](/questions/tagged/interview-questions) and [what-language-is-this-code](/questions/tagged/what-language-is-this-code). Can I get some help editing the few salvageable posts and closing/deleting the rest?

Please remember, if you're going to remove [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) from a question, make darn sure you're fixing *everything* that's wrong with that question, because people looking through the untagged list after you won't see it anymore.

Comment: I don't know if we have one of those meme graphic things for posse requests. If you know of one, feel free to edit it in.

Comment: Related: [Review task for untagged questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144131/review-task-for-untagged-questions)

Comment: And for goodness' sake, *don't* create new tags related to interview questions again!  I've had to nuke a few variations on that tag over the past few days.  There was a reason it was burninated, people.  If the question can stand alone without knowing it's an interview question, it's worth keeping.  If not, it's NARQ/Too Localized.

Comment: I went through the list and 1) edited/retagged on-topic questions 2) closed a handful of the blatantly off-topic ones. All that's left are off topic, polls, interview questions and generally broad NARQs but I'm lazy to go through them and close/delete them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the remaining [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) questions are:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115368/simple-code-review-as-a-part-of-technical-interview
- [Where to find programming projects that help science?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566915/where-to-find-programming-projects-that-help-science)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551052/how-do-i-convince-my-stingy-enterprise-to-invest-in-tools-for-developers
- [Coding Test - allow use of web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456818/coding-test-allow-use-of-web)

...all closed. I don't really feel like these have a place on Stack Overflow, but they're fairly well-written, well-answered questions so I didn't delete them straight away: if you can think of a better place for them or simply disagree that they should be disallowed, now's your chance to speak up.

And yes, there was a bit of hubub last night over the mass-retagging of 60 or so [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) questions as [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic), so here's a reminder to all: **don't fix one bad tag by making another one worse**.

Thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: Those four read to me like they'd find a fine home on [Programmers.SE]. With the possible exception of the one about finding projects.

Comment: Go ahead and migrate some/all then. They'll need good tags there as well.

Comment: BTW: casper's taking this opportunity to review the rest of [the closed questions in lang-agnostic](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blanguage-agnostic%5D+closed%3A1). Quite a bit of crud collected there over the years.

Comment: @Shog9: I don't think it is collected. Last time in July, there were over 500 questions re-tagged to language-agnostic by him.