# What happens to tags with no associated questions?

Tags: support, tags

There are some tags on that do not have any questions associated with them.

- Are these tags deleted?
- Does having an excerpt or description change anything?
- When does this happen?
- Does the reputation for tag exceprt/description disappear after the tag is deleted?

Comment: As an addition to the answer, tags with only one question get deleted after 30 days on most sites.

Comment: I believe Ral is talking about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/153008), where tags that are over 6 months old and have only been used on a single question are pruned once a month.

Answer (score 2):

> Are tags without questions associated with them deleted?

Yes.

> Does having an excerpt or description change anything?

As far as the fate of the tag is concerned, no. The information that is added to the wiki is not lost though. It is available to moderators (for some time) and can be salvaged if needed.

> When does this happen?

The script runs once every 24 hours.

> Does the reputation for tag excerpt/description disappear after the tag is deleted?

I am not sure about this one but I think, yes. Once a post is deleted, any reputation gained from editing it is lost. This behavior should extend to tag wikis and excerpts as well.