# Burninate [aardvark] (humanely)

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

With a grand total of [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2873780/1668057) tagged question for this now [defunct](http://vark.com/) service, I suggest burnination.

Failing to find a humane method, I suggest unleashing the flaming unicorn of [aardvark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aardvark) incineration:

[image]

Comment: Burninating is by definition inhumane.

Comment: This outta be good. :-)

Comment: Dexter-style syringe behind the neck before getting the flame on

Comment: Since there's been only one use, it should [automatically be burninated after 6 months](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418).

Comment: nuke the aardvark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't feel so bad when the only question with the tag is a terrible one. Question has been destroyed very inhumanely.

Answer (score 9):

You will be missed, aardvark. You will be missed. *sniff*

[image: aardvark]

(I burned it, it should be killed at 3:00 AM by the zombie tag cleanup script)

Comment: Just a note - don't *only* untag things. That question was horrid and off-topic, so a flag would definitely have been in order too. Otherwise it would have just disappeared into the depths of the PHP tag.

Comment: @anim I cleaned up the post quite a bit as well. I wasn't sure about anything else, as I really am clueless with PHP, so... :P

Comment: gave the point to @animuson, as I believe he rang the final death knell for our recently departed aardvark. Though points do not portray it in this instance, let it be known that your photo of the scrumptiously cute critter is awarded special points from the bivalves of my heart