# What happens to unanswered questions from deleted accounts?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

(By unanswered I mean with no accepted answer, as seen in the Unanswered tab.)

They're potentially bringing the numbers down in terms of completed questions.

Here are some oldies:

- [Need Help: VS 2005 Properties Changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209582/need-help-vs-2005-properties-changing)
- [How to summarize view-components/widgets-information in a JAR-File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208440/how-to-summarize-view-components-widgets-information-in-a-jar-file)
- [Microsoft Async RPC crash in Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202951/microsoft-async-rpc-crash-in-vista)
- [Silverlight 2 RTW Crashes IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202544/silverlight-2-rtw-crashes-ie7)

Or even more pertinent, questions from deleted accounts with actually no answers posted. Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226529/problem-upgrading-custom-project-from-vs2005-to-vs2008
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225190/how-do-i-export-cisco-ids-v6-1-signatures-to-excel
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250422/does-installshield-support-resuming-if-a-software-update-stops-in-the-middle-th
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239810/what-kind-of-data-to-collect-for-post-mortem-root-cause-analysis-thread-dumps-o

Thanks to balpha's SEDE magic, we now have the following statictics:

- <strike>28,192</strike> [30270](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/94578/) unanswered questions from deleted accounts
- <strike>89</strike> [96](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/94584/) unanswered questions with 0 answers from deleted accounts

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/94578/

Comment: Wow, 28 thousand is a sizeable number

Answer (score 23):

**I don't think it's particularly relevant whether the original asker is around or even deleted.**

Just FYI the following things happen automatically every week:

1. auto-deletion of questions more than 30 days old with no answers, and -1 score or lower
2. auto-deletion of questions more than 365 days old with no answers, low views, <= 1 comments, and <= 0 score

Note that "days old" is defined by *last activity* so if someone edits the question on day 364.. it'll stick around for another year.

edit: for #2, after looking at your examples, I made two changes

1. I decided to also include posts with score of 1 where the original owner is deleted -- same criteria otherwise: `AND (p.Score < 1 OR (p.Score < 2 and OwnerUserId is null))`
2. I decided to use the `CreationDate` instead of `LastActivityDate`, so community poking a question (or a user editing it) does not give a doomed question 365 more days of zombie "life".

Comment: I never knew commenting could keep low quality questions alive. I might start flagging more then. ;-)

Comment: @Arjan Soon to come: Comment flagged as "should be a flag"...

Comment: @arjan more than 1 comment, yes

Comment: (Yes, @Jeff, that was very clear. As an aside: I really appreciate it when answers contain technical details, such as the above SQL clause.)

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. That's some quality cleanup. I'm against the idea that poking a corpse turns it into a zombie. There's just no literature on that. I'll leave the question open for future discussion on the remaining 28k abandoned questions.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal:

- 0 answers provided: If more than a month old: delete
- No accepted answer, some answers provided: encourage closing through voting (maybe add a closing choice like "user account deleted and the question is not noticeable enough to be worth keeping open")

Comment: Deleting a post with answers just because it isn't *accepted* seems dangerous

Comment: @MarcGravell And I'm no longer suggesting it, see edit.