# What happened to Clickonomics?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I'd like to know why a question of mine (not the first, by the way), was deleted.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98368/clickonomics-on-se

This was an UX improvement proposal that got, at least, some positive reactions.

Two observations about Deleting Questions/Answers.

1. The poster should be notified with in some way (it's called feedback).
2. The poster should be able to see the deleted Question/Answer anyway with some big fancy icon somewhere indicating that it was deleted and why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See here:
[What happens to unanswered questions from deleted accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81887/what-happens-to-unanswered-questions-from-deleted-accounts/82408#82408).

Although the question is not relevant to you, the answer is; *questions more than 30 days old with negative votes and no answers posted to them are deleted automatically by the system.*

Comment: I was a little puzzled by the fact that it doesn't list who deleted the question.  Normally Community gets credit/blamed for stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. A pity, really.

Comment: Hmm, that *might* not be a good rule for the Meta sites. When an account is still active and the question has received an assortment of up/down votes (even if the net score of negative), we probably shouldn't delete them, considering downvotes mean something different on Meta.

Comment: @Cody, should I post a feature request? :)

Comment: [The FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) doesn't say anything about it, so maybe you could edit it.