# Do you need feedback?

Tags: discussion, feedback

There are a few features on SE that don't give any feedback to users. To name some, closed questions, deleted questions and bans. I guess, the main reason not to give feedback is to avoid discussions.

But when it happens to me, I always have a number of question; What happened? Why was this question closed or deleted? Why wasn't I informed (notified)? What can I do about it? How can I improve?

My main problem is that, without feedback, there is no way I can learn a lesson to improve my questions or answers.

Do you have the same need for feedback as I do?

**Edit** Looking at Bobby's answer, I probably should have said 'notification'. The closed questions do have feedback and in case of doubt you can always write comments to the moderators.

> [What's significantly more annoying is that suspended users do not get told why they were suspended.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102616/tell-suspended-chat-users-which-messages-were-flagged)

Comment: *"Do you have the same need for feedback as I do?"* No, I get my self-validation from within.

Comment: @Cody, it shows :)

Comment: I could imagine a bar similar to *"You've received the ... badge for ..."*, or *"Your answer to ... was migrated to ..."*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fail to see a lack of feedback, at least on closed questions. If in doubt, always read [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq).

[image: Duplicate Example]

---

[image: Offtopic Example]

---

[image: FAQ]

---

**Edit:** As it goes for deleted questions, these are edge-cases (because they need manual intervention via a Diamond-Moderator) and need to be evaluated one by one here on Meta if necessary.

Comment: personally, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: On the closed questions, of course, there is some feedback. But no 'notification'. If you don't check your own questions every once in a while, you wouldn't notice. With deleted questions, well, you wouldn't notice unless you remember you had a question there (or have +10krep).

Comment: @GUI Junkie: Direct deletion (via a Moderator) is an edge case which would need to be evaluated on a question-basis, and should rarely happen. I'm also not sure if there *is* a notification if a question is closed, I'm sure that there's a question about that already floating around on Meta.

Comment: @Jeff, maybe instead of feedback, I should have said [notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/question-deletion-notification/3398#3398). But notification is a basic form of feedback (IMO)

Comment: Bobby, I referred to the FAQ on [this deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102285/what-happened-to-clickonomics) (automatic). I'm also sure there is a question about that on Meta, but I'm asking to find out if there is a need for more notifications (feedback).

Comment: @GUI Junkie: As I said, I don't think so. Deleted questions need to be evaluated one by one *if necessary*. Providing additional feedback wouldn't change anything, considering that there's already a ton of `Why was my question closed` questions on Meta.

Comment: I don't agree with you, but I'm realizing the question is not about feedback but about notifications. Shall I put rephrase the question and publish a new one? This one can be closed or deleted.

Comment: @GUI Junkie: Yes, please open up a separate `feature-request` for that (notification on closed and deleted questions). I'm still not sure if that would do any good, but that's up to the team to decide and you're (of course) free to request that feature.

Comment: @GUI Junkie - If the OP isn't checking back on his question, how does he care if it's closed or not?

Comment: @Bo Persson, suppose I publish a question on AskUbuntu where I'm not a frequent user. I'm relying on the notification system to see answers and comments... If none are coming, should the I be held responsible for not checking? Maybe I'm in a nice discussion here on MSO and didn't have time to check back... Not that I don't care, but maybe it wasn't a top priority.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby I gave you a +1 on the great paint job ;)