# Are questions of this level welcome on SO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

This was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032650/do-while-loop-in-turbo-c-becomes-infinite-loop) which i had flagged for deletion.

> [Do-while Loop in Turbo C++ becomes infinite loop? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032650/do-while-loop-in-turbo-c-becomes-infinite-loop)

However the flag was declined.

- Why was the flag declined ?
- I have nothing against beginner questions on SO, but do we need **such** questions ?
- What happens to quality control then ?

Comment: IMO, the biggest problem with this question is that it first shows a chunk of code, then a small paragraph with the question. I'd reverse the order. EDIT: ...? I cannot edit the question?

Comment: @RobW: it's a rejected migration (closed soon after migration). Those get locked automatically by Community. So they can't be deleted or otherwise acted on by mere mortals.

Comment: The question was not closed by a moderator, it was closed by ordinary users.

Comment: @Mat Ahh.. Yes. I didnt see that. I assumed the Mod closed it, because of the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why was the flag declined ?

Why would you flag it for deletion?

The question is already closed. Posts don't necessarily have to be deleted unless they're absolute spam, in no way on topic, offensive, et cetera. This, on the other hand, is just a bad question.

Leave it as-is, there's nothing we *have* to do about it, really.

> I have nothing against beginner questions on SO, but do we need such questions ?

No. Well, there's certainly a way to ask a good beginner question. Everybody's a beginner at some point, but if you can show what you've tried and where you're stuck, this is often better than just dumping code and asking others to fix it.

The problem is not that the people asking are beginners at programming – it's that they're beginners at understanding how a Q&A site works.

And that's why these questions are downvoted and / or closed.

> What happens to quality control then ?

Quality control is already in place through the Review queues. The result is that questions with existing close votes get picked up very fast by the community. And most of the bad questions end up being closed, so I'd say the system is working.

Comment: Oh, and one thing I forgot to mention: A big problem with this post is that it was migrated from Programmers when it *probably* should have just been closed there.

Comment: At 4.2 million questions, that is all we can do to control quality of content ?

Comment: "All we do"? The close vote queue at the moment consists of 48k questions, and there have been 313k reviews since these queues exist. Furthermore, down votes on questions don't cost any reputation, so everyone's encouraged to downvote bad content when they see it. There are very strict quality filters and automatic bans in place. What else would you suggest?

Comment: I only thing that i dont understand is why is poor content kept on the site. Once its been made clear to the user that the content he posted is not welcome on the site (atleast in the way it was presented in that instance), why does it need to be there anymore ? Poor content will anyways not show up in searches, so it doesnt help anyone else or guide anyone else, other than maybe some users getting rep for no real contribution (in some instances). I certainly didnt want to offend you or anyone else, its just that i am trying to understand why certain things are the way they are.

Comment: I don't feel offended, neither would anyone else I guess :) In fact, questions that are closed [do get deleted automatically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81887/what-happens-to-unanswered-questions-from-deleted-accounts/82408#82408) as long as they meet some criteria. Also, think about this: If there weren't at least some examples of poor (closed) posts around because they were all deleted, how would other people (not the OP) know what's acceptable or not? This doesn't mean we have to keep everything of course.

Comment: I didnt know about that. Although the conditions are a little too restrictive. Two comments, or an answer can keep a question alive for all eternity :) As far as keeping content for others to see, there is lots and lots of that, much more than required for people to understand whats alright and whats not. I am not saying that every such post should be removed but, more should be done to remove such posts.

Comment: I can understand where you're coming from. I just believe that flagging for moderator attention is a little over the top here. Closed posts are not something that require immediate attention; and users with >10k reputation can vote to delete posts, and even follow up other delete votes in `/tools`. Think about the extremely large flag queue on Stack Overflow, where hundreds of flags are always waiting to be processed. Maybe another type of deletion review would be in order. (And nah, moderating is often more like doing street cleaning :P)